# Condition of closed embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

One condition, [(2) of Definition 25.4.1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HJ), for a morphism of ringed spaces $i:Z\rightarrow X$ to be a closed immersion is that 
$$O_X \rightarrow i_*O_Z$$

is surjective.

---

I have two confusions

> (a) 
>   $i^*O_X \rightarrow O_Z$ is surjective does this show $O_X \rightarrow i_*O_Z$ is surjective?  This doesn't seem to be the case for me. The counit of $i^*,i_*$ doens't seem to be special.
>
> (b) I could prove $(i^*O_X)_x=O_{X,i(x)}$ but is it the case $(i_*O_Z)_{i(z)}=(O_Z)_{z}$?

---

I do not see why both cases have to be true, it would be nice if a counter example is provided too.

Comment: b) No, the second result is just false in general, imagine for instance that $i$ isn’t injective: in $(i_*O_Z)_{i(z)}$, you would get contributions from the whole fiber above $i(z)$.

Comment: @Mindlack I think in this case the assumption is still that $i$ is a closed immersion so it's injective and you'd need different reasoning there. For the OP: you look like you have a couple typos here - one of those $i_*$ should be a $i^*$ in (a), and one of those arrows is going the wrong way.

Comment: Terribly sorry, don't know how that happened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as [the pullback of the structure sheaf is the structure sheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3077965/is-the-pull-back-of-the-structure-sheaf-the-structure-sheaf), the answer to (a) is that the natural map $i^*\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_Z$ is always an isomorphism for any morphism of schemes. So you're right to be suspicious here.

Second, $(i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)_{i(z)} = \mathcal{O}_{Z,z}$ is true. You can find this result [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_image_functor) or in most introductory algebraic geometry books. The point is that we can combine the definition $\Gamma(U,i_*\mathcal{F})=\Gamma(U\cap Z,\mathcal{F})$ for any open $U\subset X$ and any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Z$ with the fact that $Z$ has the subspace topology and every open set in $Z$ comes from the intersection of some open set in $X$ with $Z$.